# Flutter - Assertion failed: assetName != null is not true

Tags: flutter, dart

After these codes create a screenshot, an image is created at the bottom. This is the code I implemented because I wanted to drag the created image after that.

However, an error occurs during execution and the code cannot be executed. Please help me to get my code to run fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `_bytes` null-check on `Positioned` too:

```
if (bytes != null)
  Positioned(...)
```

Comment: Assertion failed when executed with the code you provided has been resolved.
I got this error. Do you know?
Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'NativeUint8List'